# How to check a Firestore map value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase cloud function that grabs a document from Firestore and needs to read a boolean value from within a `[String: Boolean]` map. In the following example, `snapshot.get("private.localNotifications")` returns that map. And `const notifyLocal = localNotifications.get("abc123")` is the attempt at getting the value for the hardcoded key, but it doesn't work.

```
admin.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(recipientUserId).get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        const notifyGlobal = snapshot.get("private.globalNotifications") || false // boolean

        if (notifyGlobal) {
            const localNotifications = snapshot.get("private.localNotifications") // [string: boolean] map
            const notifyLocal = localNotifications.get("abc123") || false // how do I check this key's value?

            if (notifyLocal) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("ERROR", error)
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual document data that you're working with.  A screenshot would work.

Comment: @DougStevenson the document data isn't the problem, the field is just a plain `[String: Bool]` map. I solved the problem (in my answer below) by casting the field `as [string, boolean]`. While this solution works, is this the preferred way to unpack Firestore maps in TypeScript?

Comment: I understand that the document data is not a problem.  I'm suggesting that seeing the actual data will help visualize what you're actually working with, in order to formulate a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map returned by Firestore must be cast to a recognizable type for the compiler to be able to parse it.

```
admin.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(recipientUserId).get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        const notifyGlobal = snapshot.get("private.globalNotifications") || false // boolean

        if (notifyGlobal) {
            const localNotifications = snapshot.get("private.localNotifications") as [string, boolean]
            const notifyLocal = localNotifications["abc123"] || false

            if (notifyLocal) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("ERROR", error)
})
```